# Creating Pdf from a button iOS swift 5 using SimplePdfBuilder or similar tool

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf

I am trying to implement a pdf create a button to create a pdf view which can then be shared in the app. I am struggling to get the pdf working. I am trying to use SimplePDFBuilder from cocapods. I'm sure I'm missing something simple so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I've not used anything to create a pdf before sorry if its a bit vague

the example pdf viewer code is below.

import UIKit
import SimplePDFBuilder

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pdf = PDFBuilder()

    pdf.withMetaAuthor("Maks")
    pdf.withMetaCreator("Maks")
    pdf.withMetaTitle("My PDF")

    pdf.addFooter(pagingEnabled: true,
                  text: "© Company copyrights reserved footer.",
                  colour: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5))

    pdf.addText(text: "Sample text")

    
}

@IBAction func pdf(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    // Build PDF Data
    let data = pdf.build()

    let pdfController = PDFPreviewVC(pdfData: data)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfController, animated: true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to create and save the file

func createPDF() {
let html = "**Hello *World!***

Generate PDF file from HTML in Swift

"
let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

```
// 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

// 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

// 4. Create PDF context and draw

let pdfData = NSMutableData()
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)

for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
    render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// 5. Save PDF file

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)
```

}

Then I loaded it into UIWebView from the documents directory with this code:

func loadPDF(filename: String) {
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension("pdf")
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}